# monacaでInAppBrowser上にツールチップなどを表示できますか？

Tags: monaca

cordovaのInAppBrowserでは、通常のonsen-uiのtoolbarやツールチップを表示させることは不可能なのでしょうか。

ページを閉じる。前のページに戻るなどといった、非常に簡単なメニューが表示されるだけで、UIのカスタマイズができません。

これは仕様なのでしょうか。なんとかして、onsenUIの部品を使えないでしょうか。

とても困っています。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: InAppBrowserを使用すると、全画面表示となるため、OnsenUIが表示されません。対応としては、onspageタグ内でiframeを使用して表示サイズを調整する方法があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
iframeを利用する方法は試してみたのですが、すぐにアプリが落ちてしまい、泣く泣く諦めました。
どうやらmonacaでは、inappbrowserのデザイン変更などはできないようですね…。

Answer (score 1):

同じ回答が[旧フォーラム](https://monaca.mobi/ja/forum/q/5481275f7e2193fa2e696990)でありましたので回答します。
InAppBrowserは実際HTMLを埋め込むWebViewとは別のWebViewを立ち上げるので管理が出来ません。
これを管理しようとすると後述しますが、自分でCordovaプラグインを作成し管理する必要があります。
下記にリンク先#4の回答を引用します。

> 自分が考え付く方法は
>   １．iframeをHTML全体に広げ表示する
>   ２．リンク先のソースをAjaxで取得し、ソレをHTML内に動的に追加する
>   (自分の管理しているページのみしか使えませんが……)
>   ３．Cordovaプラグインを作成しOnsenUIのHTML部分に埋め込む
>   (簡易的なWebViewを作成してDIVに対して反映する形でしょうか)
>   難易度もそのまま番号順ですかね。
>   1番目は自由なブラウジングを行おうとすると危険が付きまとうので
>   sandbox属性を付与するか、もしくは自分の管理するページのみでの使用になります。
>   2番目は自分の管理するページのみの仕様になります。
>   OnsenUIをどのようなレイアウトで使用するのか分かりませんが
>   大体はHTMLを取得後、内のscriptを取得してons-pageの中に反映する形になるかと思います。
>   3番目は誰かが作っているかもしれませんが、
>   無ければ作るしかないので悪しからず。
>   InAppBrowserでOnsenUIの表示は出来ませんね
>   ツールバーやタブバーの機能を持たないヘッダーフッターの反映なら
>   サーバー側にOnsenUIを仕込むことで可能だとは思いますが……